# What does 'limited' mean in the passage?

Tags: meaning

Does it mean 'that the people in the hallucinations have the limited range of actions'?

> Sometimes, she said, before the people come on, she may hallucinate
>   pink and blue squares on the floor, which seem to go up to the
>   ceiling. I said, "Is this like a dream?" And she said, "No, it's not
>   like a dream. It's like a movie." She said, "It's got color. It's got
>   motion. But it's completely silent, like a silent movie." And she said
>   that it's a rather boring movie. She said, "All these people with
>   Eastern dress, walking up and down, very repetitive, very **limited**."

https://www.ted.com/talks/oliver_sacks_what_hallucination_reveals_about_our_minds

Answer (score 1):

"Limited" can mean "lacking something." I don't know the full context of this passage, but here's one possibility of what that could mean. The speaker might think that because the people in Eastern dress are walking up and down repetitively, they are "limited" because they lack more interesting, dynamic, and unique movements.